# Can same inputstream be used in streamreader

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

I need to do processes on a file ,first count the number of lines and compare with a value.

The next is one to read thru the file line by line and do validations.

if first one passes only i need to do second process.

I read the same file using FTP.

When i try to create a different input stream...ftp is busy reading the current file.

like this   :

```
(is1 = ftp.getFile(feedFileName);)
```

below is the remaining :

```
 InputStream is = null;
LineNumberReader lin = null;
    LineNumberReader lin1 = null;
is = ftp.getFile(feedFileName);  
lin = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

so can i just use like below:

```
 is1=is;
```

Will both streams be having the file contents from start to finish or the second object will become null as soon as the first stream object is read.

So is the only option left is to create a new ftp object to read a stream seperately ?

Comment: What does 'ftp is busy reading the current file' mean. Any exceptions?

Comment: Yes exception occurs when i give :is1=ftp.getFile(feedFileName);   Since ftp is already reading to is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you are done with the LineNumberReader, close the InputStream `is`. Then re-request the file from FTP, it will not be busy then anymore. You cannot 'just' read from the same InputStream, as that one is probably exhausted by the time the LineNumberReader is done. Furthermore, not all InputStreams support the `mark()` and `reset()` methods.

However I'd suggest that doing the second process only when the first one succeeds might not be the right way. As you're streaming the data anyways, why not stream it into a temporary data structure and then count the lines and then operate on the same data structure.

Comment: I need to count the lines and see if it equals the count mentioned in the same file.Only if its equal ,i need to do the validations of the file contents line be line which are nothing but person records in csv format.So when i finish counting and done with first validation ,i need the stream from the start.So am puzzled on what to do next ...Can you please suggest if possible on how to load the contents of the file to a data structure and then count it.

Comment: You're already using an InputStreamReader which you feed into the LineNumberReader. If you first cache all the read lines in a `List<String>`, then you can do the same, and don't need to stream the file twice.

Answer (score 4):

It can, but you would need to "rewind" the InputStream. First you need to call mark() method on it, and then reset. Here are docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset()

Comment: Can you give me a coding demo please ?

Answer (score 1):

if you file is not big, you can save data to a String.
liek:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len = is.read(buffer))!=-1)
sb.append(buffer, 0, len);
String data = sb.toString();
```

then you can do further thing in the String
like:

```
int lineNumber = data.split("\n").length;
```